# How to get exact match phrase more than one

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl, elasticsearch-dsl

Below is the query to get the exact match

```
GET courses/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term" : {
         "name.keyword": "Anthropology 230"
      }
  }
}
```

I need to find the `Anthropology 230` and `Anthropology 250 also`

How to get the exact match

Comment: but how **Anthropology 230** is `exact` match with **Anthropology 230 also** ?

Comment: @aysh can u share your sample index data also? And can you please tell what is your expected result based on that index data?

Comment: @AlwaysSunny its 250, so basically it has to match 2 values 230 and 250

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake that you are doing is that you are using the term query on keyword field and both of them are not analyzed, which means they try to find the exact same search string in inverted index.

What you should be doing is: define a `text` field which you anyway will have if you have not defined your mapping. I am also assuming the same as in your query you mentioned `.keyword` which gets created automatically if you don't define mapping.

Now you can just use below [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) which is analyzed and uses [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) which splits the token on whitespace, so `Anthropology` `250` and `230` will be generated for your 2 sample docs.

**Simple and efficient query which brings both the docs**

```
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "name" : "Anthropology 230"
        }
    }
}
```

**And search result**

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "matchterm",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.8754687,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Anthropology 230"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "matchterm",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.18232156,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Anthropology 250"
        }
      }
    ]
```

The reason why above query matched both docs is that it created two tokens `anthropology` and `230` and matches `anthropology` in both of the documents.

You should definitely read about the [analysis process](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer-anatomy.html) and can also try [analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) to see the tokens generated for any text.

**Analyze API output for your text**

POST http://{{hostname}}:{{port}}/{{index-name}}/_analyze

```
{
  "analyzer": "standard",
  "text": "Anthropology 250"
}


{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "anthropology",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 12,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "250",
            "start_offset": 13,
            "end_offset": 16,
            "type": "<NUM>",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can check and try with, [match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html), [match_phrase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) or [match_phrase_prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html)

Using **match**,

```
GET courses/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "name" : "Anthropology 230"
        }
    },
    "_source": "name"
}
```

Using **match_phrase**,

```
GET courses/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase" : {
            "name" : "Anthropology"
        }
    },
    "_source": "name"
}
```

**OR** using [regexp](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html),

```
GET courses/_search
{
    "query": {
        "regexp" : {
            "name" : "Anthropology [0-9]{3}"
        }
    },
    "_source": "name"
}
```

Comment: `match_phrase` and `match_phrase_prefix` is overkill here and can cause other issues if OP is not looking for phrase match and regex queries are expensive, glad you added `match` query option :)

Comment: @Always Sunny if you use ```match_phrase``` query, then it will not match both the documents, **it will only match one document that contains ```Anthropology 230```**

Comment: @Bhavya, agreed and I know that :), I had a typo, I meant **Anthropology** only, also I agree the match is better in this case as `@Ninja` mentioned

Comment: to downvoter: what is the reason for voting it down?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you may have more 'Anthropology nnn' items, this should do what you need:

```
"query":{
    "bool":{
        "must":[
            {"term": {"name.keyword":"Anthropology 230"}},
            {"term": {"name.keyword":"Anthropology 250"}},
        ]  
    }
}
```